# Assimp cannot load vertices color of PLY model

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, assimp, ply-file-format

I'm using the assimp3.0 on windows with OpenGL. I tried to load and display a ply model by following lines:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;
const aiScene* scene = NULL;
scene = importer.ReadFile('filename', 0);
```

I built the vertex buffer with `scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices` and color buffer with `scene->mMeshes[0]->mColors`
However, when I debug the code, only `scene->mMeshes[0]->mColors[0]` got the colors, `scene->mMeshes[0]->mColors[1]` and the following elements remains to be NULL
following is a short ply example I I wrote:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 3
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha
element face 1
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
0.0 0.0 0.0 219 227 248 255
1.0 0.0 0.0 220 230 212 255
2.0 0.0 2.0 160 122 221 255
3 0 1 2
```

I'm currently wondering if it was caused by the wrong pFlags parameter of `importer.ReadFile(pFile,pFlags)`.

Can anyone help me figure out which part went wrong.

Comment: In the ReadFile method try sending pFlags as aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Quality. However, it should not matter in this case.

Comment: I tried it, but it still won't load the color information for vertices except the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understood the problem.

You are reading colours like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
    vertexColor = scene->mMeshes[0]->mColors[i];
```

However, AssImp can store more than one vertex colour channel, so you are suppose to read it like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
    vertexColor = scene->mMeshes[0]->mColors[0][i];
```

This will read the colours in the 0th vertex colour channel

Comment: I know that the mColors is an array of vector3d. The problem is that only mColors[0] got the correct value say..[0.9,0.8,0.9], but mColors[1] got NULL and it's the same for the following spaces..

Comment: Read the values like this.
mColors[0][0], mColors[0][1], mColors[0][2], mColors[0][3], mColors[0][4], ... , mColors[0][n] where n is number of vertices. 
There is one vertex colour channel in the ply so all colour values are aside the 2 dimensional array